# trying to set focus on a hidden text box

Tags: jquery

I am trying to set focus on a hidden text box. I want that when the body or div containing the text box loads the focus should be on the particular text box so that any input from key board or any other device is caught by this element. I have tried the following code with no effect:

```
<body>
    <input type="text" id="exp" maxlength="16"></input>
    <input type="text" id="exp2" maxlength="16"></input>
    <script>
        $("#exp").hide();
        $("#exp").focus();
        $("#exp2").keypress(function(){
            alert($("#exp").val());
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

make any suggestions. jquery solution will be preferred.

Comment: Hidden elements can't gain focus, by design. What exactly you expect to happen?? You can set focus when it's still visible then hide it.

Comment: Hidden element has display:none; so how can they be focused .by Barbosa

Comment: I can't imagine why you would want to do this. Plus input tags are self closing tags. <input/>

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can't set focus to a text box that is hidden through the `hide` method. Instead, you need to move it off screen.

```
<body>
<!-- it's better to close inputs this way for the sake of older browsers -->
<input type="text" id="exp" maxlength="16" />
<input type="text" id="exp2" maxlength="16" />
<script>
// Move the text box off screen
$("#exp").css({
    position: 'absolute',
    top: '-100px'
});
$("#exp").focus();
$("#exp2").keypress(function(){
alert($("#exp").val());
});
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: by doing this the #exp will never be able to come back to it's previous place

Comment: Usually you don't want a hidden text box which is being used to capture keys to come back into view. But you can bring it back to its previous place: `$('#exp').css('position', 'static');`

Comment: That meets my requirements...although it was not what I was looking for...it sems a bit of the box solution....:)...thanks anyways...

Comment: ;-)  Believe it or not, this is a pretty standard solution. Cheers!

Comment: true story!! :P (you may also try to z-index it down, but it may give problems with some mobile browsers..)

Answer (score 1):

```
visibility:hidden; 
position: absolute;
```

Works in Chrome 53, and seems cleaner than trying to shift the element offscreen as in Nathan Wall's answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible via async/await where the code to select the input only runs *after* the code to display the input returns its fulfilled promise.

```
let selectInput = async () => {
    await setInputDisplayBlock();
    document
        .getElementById("input")
        .focus();
};
selectInput();
```